# using xmlagg to find count to concatenate

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ent.entity_key_id AS query1kid,
    CAST(substr(rtrim(XMLAGG(xmlelement(e,alstd.relationship_desc
                                                    ||
        CASE
            WHEN(alstd.joint_flag = 'No' AND ent.anonymous_flag = 'No') THEN ''
            ELSE('('
                   ||
                CASE
                    WHEN alstd.joint_flag = 'Yes' THEN 'Joint'
                    ELSE ''
                END
                   ||
                CASE
                    WHEN ent.anonymous_flag = 'Yes' THEN ',Anon'
                    ELSE ''
                END
                   || ')')
        END
                                                    || ': '
                                                    || allocthm.allocation_description
                                                    || '('
                                                    || substr(allocthm.allocation_code,5,6) || ***count(ben.entity_key_ID)***
                                                    || ')',',').extract('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            ent.entity_key_id
    ).getclobval(),','),1,4000) AS VARCHAR(4000) ) AS displayfiled1 
FROM
                    er_datamart.allocation_theme allocthm
            left JOIN er_datamart.allocation_stewardee alstd ON (allocthm.allocation_code = alstd.allocation_code and alstd.status_code <> 'F')
            INNER JOIN er_datamart.entity_d ent ON alstd.entity_key_id = ent.entity_key_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ER_DATAMART.ALLOCATION_BENEFICIARY ben ON ben.allocation_code  = allocthm.allocation_code 


GROUP BY 
    ent.entity_key_id
```

This gives me an error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

I'm trying to find the `count(ben.entity_key_ID)` so that I can have it appended to my already functional query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `count()` inside the `xmlagg()` - you have nested group functions that the group-by clause can't handle.

You can move the string concatenation into an inline view with its own group-by to get that count, and then perform the XML aggregation from that; something like:

```
SELECT
   entity_key_id AS query1kid,
   CAST(substr(rtrim(
      XMLAGG(xmlelement(e, constructed_string, ',').extract('//text()')
         ORDER BY entity_key_id
   ).getclobval(),','),1,4000) AS VARCHAR(4000) ) AS displayfiled1 
FROM (
   SELECT ent.entity_key_id,
      alstd.relationship_desc
            ||
         CASE
            WHEN(alstd.joint_flag = 'No' AND ent.anonymous_flag = 'No') THEN ''
            ELSE('('
            ||
         CASE
            WHEN alstd.joint_flag = 'Yes' THEN 'Joint'
            ELSE ''
         END
            ||
         CASE
            WHEN ent.anonymous_flag = 'Yes' THEN ',Anon'
            ELSE ''
        END
           || ')')
        END
           || ': '
           || allocthm.allocation_description
           || '('
           || substr(allocthm.allocation_code,5,6) || count(ben.entity_key_ID)
           || ')' as constructed_string
   FROM
       allocation_theme allocthm
   LEFT JOIN allocation_stewardee alstd
   ON allocthm.allocation_code = alstd.allocation_code and alstd.status_code <> 'F'
   INNER JOIN entity_d ent
   ON alstd.entity_key_id = ent.entity_key_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ALLOCATION_BENEFICIARY ben
   ON ben.allocation_code  = allocthm.allocation_code 
   GROUP BY
      ent.entity_key_id,
      alstd.relationship_desc,
      alstd.joint_flag,
      ent.anonymous_flag,
      allocthm.allocation_description,
      allocthm.allocation_code
)
GROUP BY 
   entity_key_id
```

The `ELSE ''` parts are redundant as that is the default behaviour but you might prefer to keep them for clarity/explicitness. Your joint/anon part might need a bit more work - if joint is No and anon is Yes you get `(,Anon)` - I think - which looks a bit odd, but might be what you need.